# Access protected member

Tags: java, protected

I have an instance variable in the class Avo, package ger1, with protected modifier.

```
package ger1;  

public class Avo {  
    protected int i = 1;  
}
```

Then I have a class Pai which is in package ger2, extends Avo and accesses the variable by instance, so far normal...

```
package ger2;  

public class Pai extends Avo {  
    public Pai() {  
        i++  
    }  
}
```

But Kathy Sierra's book says of the protected member, "Once the subclass-outside-the-package inherits the  protected member, that member (as inherited by the subclass) becomes private to any code outside the subclass, with the exception of subclasses of the subclass."

But if i try to access the member through instance of class Pai it's allowed! However the Filho class must be in the same package of Avo. Why this? It's normal?

```
package ger1;  

import ger2.Pai;  

public class Filho {  
    public Filho() {  
        Pai pai = new Pai();  
        pai.i++;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a reference (as in, a link or something like that) to the book you mean? In the meantime, to clear up questions on access modifiers, I'd recommend the java tutorials http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: The book is "Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide" by Kathy Sierra, page 36.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. "protected" means visible in sub-classes, even if they are in a separate package.

Edit: see also this question
 [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: Correct, but I think he asked if whether a protected attribute is visible or not to a non sub-class of the same package (which is also true).

Comment: Even through instance (not by inheritance), for another class that inherits the protected member in another package?

Comment: Yes, which is why I linked to the other question, which provides a much more detailed answer.  See the answer with over 300 upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `pai.i++;` is made in the `ger1` package.

Your protected int value is declared in the `ger1` package, meaning the same as above.

**So, `i` is reachable since `protected` values are accessible by all class residing in the same package.**

To expect the case that the Kathy Sierra's book wrote, **just move the `Filho` class from `ger1` package to `ger2` package.**

So that you will notice that `i` appeared unreachable :)